# Sitecore redirect to media file items

Tags: iis, sitecore, sitecore8, url-rewrite-module

I have redesigned a site from static html pages to Sitecore (8.0). I am setting up Url Rewrite maps in IIS. Rewrite maps that map from what was a PDF on the old site to a media item on the new site do not seem to be working. Here is an example map:

```xml
<add key="/PDF/ARandomPdfName.pdf" value="/~/media/Files/TopLevelFolder/SubFolder/ARandomPdfName.ashx" />
```

If I browse to the key I get a 404. If I browse to the value, I see the PDF. Do I need to do something special for media file redirects?

Comment: Did you also add a rule to reference your rewrite map and do the redirects? http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Yes. I created a tester to loop through all the maps ind actually try hitting the site to see what comes back. Its seems that some Pdfs work. Its when there is a space in the name of the pdf, for example /PDF/TRS_TRR%20Reconsideration%20Request%20Form%20June2016.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This problem I dont think had anything to do with Sitecore. In the rewrite maps, IIS does not seem to want encoded spaces.

Old way that did not work:

```xml
<add key="/PDF/Clinical%20Preventive%20Care%20Brief%20-%20Adult-%20FINAL.pdf" value="/~/media/Files/Providers/medical-care-briefs/clinical-preventive-services-brief/clinical-preventive-care-brief---adult--final.ashx" />
```

So, I removed the encoded spaces (%20) to end up with:

```xml
<add key="/PDF/Clinical Preventive Care Brief - Adult- FINAL.pdf" value="/~/media/Files/Providers/medical-care-briefs/clinical-preventive-services-brief/clinical-preventive-care-brief---adult--final.ashx" />
```

And this works. If I browse to:

http://myhostname.com/PDF/Clinical%20Preventive%20Care%20Brief%20-%20Adult-%20FINAL.pdf

I get redirected correctly.